# конфигурация приложения неправильна visual studio c++ TRK0002

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Скачал исходный код нужного мне dll на GitHub. При сборке ошибки в коде не наблюдаются, однако наблюдается ошибка неправильной конфигурации MSBuild. При чем если создать проект или открыть другой, ошибка пропадет. Вот сама ошибка

> Ошибка TRK0002 не удалось выполнить команду: ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x86\CL.exe" @C:\Users\DimoNULL\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildTempDimoNULL\tmp9b96bf94c6334cdc91d86d5394f142b5.rsp". Не удалось запустить приложение, поскольку его параллельная конфигурация неправильна. Дополнительные сведения содержатся в журнале событий приложений или используйте программу командной строки sxstrace.exe для получения дополнительных сведений.  NFSMWExtraOptions   C:\Users\DimoNULL\Documents\NFSMWExOpts-master\NFSMWExtraOptions\TRACKER    1